# How do I get Azure AD OAuth2 Access Token and Refresh token for Daemon or Server to C# ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, azure, security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have implemented an Azure AD OAuth2 Daemon or Server to ASP.NET Web API.
However I only receive an access token which is the property on the AuthenticationResult. See implementation below.

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetAccessToken(string clientId, string clientkey)
    {
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientkey);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientCredential).Result;
        Authorisation authorisation = new Authorisation {access_token = authenticationResult.AccessToken,
                                                token_type = authenticationResult.AccessTokenType,
                                                expires_on = authenticationResult.ExpiresOn };

        return Ok(authorisation);
    }
```

This returns only access token. I would like an implementation, a Daemon or Server implementation that returns both access token and refresh token. Have your seen or done similar implementation. Any useful links to an example are welcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I posted this question, this was the answer I was looking for, please see screen shot below for expected result and c# console solution.
Having found the solution, it is worth sharing it here, may be useful to someone some day

**C# console app code to achieve expected result in the postman screen shot below**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace AzureADTokenApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0";
            var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "<azure ad client id e.g. 9b864-a5e6-4f0d-b155-1f53a6c78>"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "<azure ad client secret e.g. MTMiXaO1P9HnhSawdXWmcnuQ="),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "<azure ad user e.g. julius.depulla@example.com>"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "<azure ad user password e.g. Pa$$word01>"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "openid")
             };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

            var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;

            string result = string.Empty;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot from Postman - Expected Result. You will have same result in console except is less readable**

[image]

Comment: The response shows 400 for me. Is the `tenant-name` actually display name for application?

Comment: tenant-name is the name for your Azure-AD

Comment: How to find your tenant name:  https://helpdesk.kaseya.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115002521251-How-Do-I-Find-My-Azure-AD-Tenant-Name-

Comment: Hi @JuliusDepulla, to run your code can you please tell what i should have set in my azure directory? I saw many documentations that really confused me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the client credentials flow. In that flow, a refresh token should not be included https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.3. Also it looks like you are using ADAL v3, which anyways doesn't return refresh tokens (by design), but it uses them automatically for you. More info here http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/13/adal-3-didnt-return-refresh-tokens-for-5-months-and-nobody-noticed/

Comment: I desire a refresh token and an access token, would you know any other library in C# that can be used

Comment: ADAL v2 return refresh tokens, if the OAuth flow you are using uses them

Comment: You are right ADAL v2 does return refresh token, but ADAL is in v3 now, if I use v2 I will missing out on updates/patches to the ADAL Library

Comment: Well I am not aware of any other MS library for this. Perhaps there is a non MS library. Or perhaps you can manually build the HTTP requests needed to acquire access / refresh tokens (in essence, do the same that ADAL does for you). But as it's described in the blog I mentioned in my post, ADAL v3 has good reasons for not returning refresh tokens but using them automatically for you. Perhaps it would help if you start a new thread/question describing the scenario you are trying to solve and why you need to manipulate refresh tokens instead of letting ADAL manipulate the refresh tokens for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use the refresh token to redeem to access token manually if you were developing with ADAL v3.

In this scenario, we should use the `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` and catch the exception. After the access_token is expired, we should re-initialize `AuthenticationContext` and call the `AcquireTokenAsync` again to send the request to acquire the access_token.

Here is a code sample for your reference:

```
class Program
{
    static string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/adfei.onmicrosoft.com";
    static string resrouce = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
    static string clientId = "";
    static string secret = "";
    static ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
    static AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var client = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(request =>
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", GetAccessToken());
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }));

            var users = client.Users.Request().GetAsync().Result.CurrentPage;
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
            }          
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 5);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    static string GetAccessToken()
    {
        try
        {
            var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resrouce, credential).Result.AccessToken;             
            return token;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            return GetAccessToken();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Xue-MSFT  `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` always throws an exception `AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException`. It would have been a solution if before you acquire the access token for the first time, it throws an exception, but subsequent request before the access token expires it returns the access token

Comment: @JuliusDepulla To make the `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` to work in the first time, the application should call the `AcquireTokenAsync` manually before calling `AcquireTokenSilentAsync`. The initializing calling `AcquireTokenAsync` will get the `access_token` and `refresh_token` to ensure that the following call `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` successfully.

Comment: Xue-MSFT I am using ADAL v3 in daemon/server/console app to Web API scenario and it does not return access/refresh tokens. ADAL v2 however does.  If you think otherwise please post a complete solution here, I will appreciate your help.

Comment: @JuliusDepulla sorry for the misleading. After the further investigation, the scenario will not work for you since the client credentials flow doesn't return the refresh_token(refer [4.4.3. Access Token Response](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#page-42)). We can re-initialize the `authContext` and call  `AcquireTokenAsync` to send the request to get the access_token again when the access_token is expired. And I will modify the reply to append a code sample for your reference.

Comment: Xue-MSFT  Many thanks for your help. The reference is very useful. Looking forward to the code sample from you. Regards.

Comment: @Xue-MSFT. Many thanks for the code sample, but I notice you never call `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` in the code sample. You only call `AcquireTokenAsync` . Can I ask a question please? Can I send a username and password of a user registered in Azure AD, and use that for authentication without a login screen?