# Google API .NET Client - How do I get OAuth2 Access Token and Refresh token for C# ASP.NET Core Web API client to authenticate YouTube Data API v3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

How do I get OAuth2 Access Token and Refresh token for C# ASP.NET Core Web API client to authenticate YouTube Data API v3

There is no UI for a username to manually enter their username and password, then receive code to get the token in this scenario. No redirect_uri is required.

How can I get the access token and refresh token

I once solved a similar issue with [Microsoft Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161892/how-do-i-get-azure-ad-oauth2-access-token-and-refresh-token-for-daemon-or-server), solution on stackoverflow

I just can't find any information regarding Google Cloud Platform .NET clients for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can not use client login (username and password) with any Google api since 2015.  You will need to use Oauth2 in order to authenticate your user.

You will need to configure the library first.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    // This configures Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3 for use in this app.
    services
        .AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            // This forces challenge results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, so there's no
            // need to add an AccountController that emits challenges for Login.
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // This forces forbid results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, which checks if
            // extra scopes are required and does automatic incremental auth.
            o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // Default scheme that will handle everything else.
            // Once a user is authenticated, the OAuth2 token info is stored in cookies.
            o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = {YOUR_CLIENT_ID};
            options.ClientSecret = {YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET};
        });
}
      

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    ...
}
```

Then you can make any call you like to the YouTube API.  When this endpoint is hit the user will be prompted to consent to authorization.

```
[GoogleScopedAuthorize(YouTubeService.ScopeConstants.Readonly)]
public async Task<IActionResult> YouTubeCall([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
{
    GoogleCredential cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
    var service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = cred
    });
    
    // your call to the youTube service here.

}
```

I recommend having a look at the sample for [Asp .net core](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#configure-your-application-to-use-google.apis.auth.aspnetcore3) however it is in google drive you will need to alter it.

The client library should be handing all the access tokens and refresh tokens for you, but if you really want to access them there is a bit of information on how here [#1725](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1725#issuecomment-754692970)

Comment: In my scenario a user will not be present, because it is API to API authentication.
Had help from amanda-tarafa and jskeet from Google Cloud Platform .NET Client team.
Instead of using Web Application Google API Service Credential, use Desktop Credential instead together with the API Key and it works. 
Solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1739)
When you receive the token, you then use the token received to make your request to YouTube Data API.